# After cloning repository from bitbucket shows dll missing error

Tags: repository, bitbucket

I'm working on Visual studio 2014 and I have pushed my Project in a Bitbucket repository. I've successfully cloned the same repository in another machine. But the problem is that this other machine shows that a lot of .dll files are missing. How to solve it?

Please look at [this screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTZc9.png).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely because `*.dll` appears in a `gitignore_global.txt` file. Though my local repository did not actually have a `gitignore` file, I found this global file within my C-drive's `MyDocument` folder.

What eventually worked for me, in order to get the DLLs into Bitbucket, was to navigate through Git Bash to the folder containing the DLLs, and use the command:

```
git add <AssemblyName>.dll -f
```

Comment: Thanks @NathanielFord...SO answering newbie here